# RAD runAnt.sh failed

Tags: build, ant, rad, ibm-rational

I have clean installed Rational Application Developer(RAD) v9.7 and Websphere Application Server(WAS) Traditional for Developers v8.5.5.15. I'm trying to export EAR file headless mode using runAnt.sh script. Although i follow the steps on [knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS8PJ7_9.7.0/com.ibm.ant.tasks.doc/topics/trunautobuild.html) i'm getting following error in ".log" file of RAD. if you know what is wrong could you please let me know too.

```
!SESSION 2019-07-13 02:37:18.785
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=unknown java.fullversion=8.0.5.30 - pxa6480sr5fp30-20190207_01(SR5 FP30) JRE 1.8.0 Linux amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190124_408237 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) OpenJ9   - 9c77d86 OMR      - dad8ba7 IBM      - e2996d1 BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rbu.product.v97.rbu -buildfile /opt/IBM/SDP/samples/AutoBuild/AdderBuild.xml importAndBuildEverything Command-line arguments:  -product com.ibm.rational.rbu.product.v97.rbu
-data /tmp/ws -os linux -ws gtk -buildfile /opt/IBM/SDP/samples/AutoBuild/AdderBuild.xml importAndBuildEverything

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.app 0 0 2019-07-13 02:37:20.092 !MESSAGE Product com.ibm.rational.rbu.product.v97.rbu could not be found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jetty.plus 2 0 2019-07-13 02:37:20.465 !MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.jetty.plus [2158]   Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.   org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.jetty.plus [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.plus"] because it is exposed to package 'org.eclipse.jetty.util.log' from resources org.eclipse.jetty.util [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.util"] and org.eclipse.jetty.util [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.11.v20180605"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.util"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:   org.eclipse.jetty.plus [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.plus"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)(&(version>=9.4.8)(!(version>=9.4.9))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log   org.eclipse.jetty.util [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.util"]

Chain 2:   org.eclipse.jetty.plus [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.plus"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi)(&(version>=9.4.8)(!(version>=9.4.9))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.jndi; uses:=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log   org.eclipse.jetty.jndi [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.8.v20171121"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.jndi"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)(&(version>=9.4.0)(!(version>=10.0.0))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: org.eclipse.jetty.util.log   org.eclipse.jetty.util [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="9.4.11.v20180605"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jetty.util"]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-13 02:37:20.466 !MESSAGE Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.RuntimeException: No application id has been found.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the answer here in case someone comes across this error someday.
As stated [here](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm%7ERational&product=ibm/Rational/IBM%20Rational%20Application%20Developer%20for%20WebSphere%20Software&release=9.7.0&platform=Linux&function=fixId&fixids=9.7.0.1-Rational-RAD-groupfixpack,Rational-RAD-Java8SR5FP30_RAD_RSA-ifix,Rational-RAD-PH06298ifix-ifix,Rational-RAD-Java8SR5FP25_RAD_RSA-ifix&includeRequisites=1&includeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&login=true) interim fix: Rational-RAD-PH06298ifix-ifix solved the problem.